# How to launch projectile mode with default configuration

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, projectile, prefix-keys

I looked at the quickstart here:

- https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#installation
- https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/

And have this in my init.el:

```lisp
(require 'projectile)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'projectile-command-map)
(projectile-mode +1)
```

I can launch with `C-c p` but what is `s-p` ?  Is that the "*windows*" button + p? `Shift`?

Comment: it's `super`, it can be bound to windows, and usually it'll be. `shift` is `S`.

Comment: `C-c p` does appear to put `C-c p-` at the bottom and expect additional input like a prefix, but `super/windows-p` does nothing.  It should be the same, right?

Comment: I should, but it doesn't have to be. _windows_ key might not be mapped to super, hijacked by your OS, or shadowed. Use `C-h k` `s-p` to see what is going on with it inside emacs.

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to fit the question or its tags. Is the question about key bindings? Is it about how to turn on `projectile-mode`? Unclear, so far.

Answer (score 1):

You pick one of those 2 prefix options, depending on your operating system.

"s-p" is (mostly) for macOS, meaning "command-p"

See the comments:

```
;; Recommended keymap prefix on macOS
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)
;; Recommended keymap prefix on Windows/Linux
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'projectile-command-map)
```

Reference: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile

To learn more about basic keybindings with these prefixes, see https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/usage.html#basic-usage